# Getting an id or a name of child element in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an ExpandableListView of categories and items (each item belongs to category). For now I just want to get the ID or the Name of a clicked item in the list and show it in a Toast message. But when I click on an item nothing happens, no Toast.

This is my ExpandableListView adapter (the relevant parts):

```
public class Expandable_ListView_Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<Category> arr_categories;
Context context;

public Expandable_ListView_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Category> categories)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    arr_categories = categories;
    this.context=context;
}


@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return arr_categories.get(groupPosition).getCategory_items().get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {

    Category category = arr_categories.get(groupPosition);
    int category_id = category.getCategory_id();

    return category_id;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    Category category = arr_categories.get(groupPosition);
    Base_Item base_item = category.getCategory_items().get(childPosition);
    int id = base_item.getItem_id();

    Toast.makeText(context, "Category: "+category.getCategory_name() + ", \nItem: "+base_item.getItem_name()
            + "\nID: "+id,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return id;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Category category = arr_categories.get(groupPosition);

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_category, parent, false);
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_name)).setText(category.getCategory_name());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Category category = arr_categories.get(groupPosition);
    final Base_Item base_item = category.getCategory_items().get(childPosition);

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_base_item, parent, false);
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_base_item_name)).setText(base_item.getItem_name());

    return convertView;
}
```

And this is the code in my Fragment:

```
public class Fragment_Master_List extends Fragment {

Task_DB_Manager manager;
Expandable_ListView_Adapter adapter;
ArrayList<Category> arr_all_categories;
ExpandableListView master_lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_master_list, container, false);

    master_lv = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.elv_master_list);

    manager = new Task_DB_Manager(getActivity());
    arr_all_categories = manager.get_all_categories();
    adapter = new Expandable_ListView_Adapter(getActivity(), arr_all_categories);
    master_lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    master_lv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: "+arr_all_categories.get(groupPosition).getCategory_items().get(childPosition).getItem_name().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item id: "+adapter.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

How come I don't get a toast when I click on an item (child) and how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found a solution! I had to change this automatically created method, which I thought to be irrelevant, to return true instead of false:

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```